# Im having an issue when running a class design, need help figuring out where is the issue

Tags: python

```
    # Classy Mandelbrot Patterns.

import turtle;
import colorsys;

# A Mandelbrot patterns class:
class MandelbrotPatterns:
    # Initialize the pen, and determine the window width and height:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen = turtle.Pen(); 
        self.width = self.pen.window_width();
        self.height = self.pen.window_height();

# Given numbers self, u0, v0, and side, design a pattern:
def mandelbrot(self, u0, v0, side):
    self.pen.tracer(False);   
    for x in range(-self.width/2, +self.width/2):
        for y in range (-self.height/2, +self.height/2):
            draw(self.pen, side, u0, v0, x, y);
        if (x % 20 == 0):
            self.pen.tracer(True); self.pen.tracer(False);
    self.pen.tracer(True);

# Draw in color a pattern element at point (x, y):
def selfdraw(self, side, u0, v0, x, y):
    maxCount = 25;
    u = u0 + x * (side / 100.0);
    v = v0 - y * (side / 100.0);
    a = 0 ; b = 0; count = 0; 
    while (count < maxCount and a * a + b * b <= 4):
        count = count + 1;
        a1 = a * a - b * b + u;
        b1 = 2 * a * b + v;
        a = a1; b = b1;
    ez = float(count) / maxCount;
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(ez, ez, ez);
    self.pen.color(color);
    self.pen.up(); self.pen.goto(x, y); self.pen.down();
    self.pen.forward(1);
```

when I run the module Im testing this information to make sure it works:

```
>>> mb = MandelbrotPatterns();
>>> mb.mandelbrot(u0= -0.5, v0 = 0, side = 1);
```

This is the response I'am getting back from Idle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
        mb.mandelbrot(-0.5, 0, 1)
    AttributeError: MandelbrotPatterns instance has no attribute 'mandelbrot'
```

I was thinking where I define mandelbrot is the problem but I don't see where there could be an error. If someone could give me an idea or solution that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your methods need to be indented one level further. As it is, they're functions defined at the same level as the class.

Comment: are you referringto this part                                       ez = float(count) / maxCount;
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(ez, ez, ez);
    self.pen.color(color);
    self.pen.up(); self.pen.goto(x, y); self.pen.down();
    self.pen.forward(1);

Comment: I'm referring to [the Whole. Damn. Method.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: What I V-A is saying is that *every line* starting from `# Given numbers`. . . must be indented one tab, so that all the `def` statements line up with `def __init__()`.

Comment: OK, thank you for clearing that up for me @Larry. Im very new to python, so still trying to learn.

Comment: The use of indentation to define program structure is one of the defining characteristics of Python.  Once you get used to it, it's hard to go back to languages that ignore white space.

Comment: I fixed the indentation but im getting a different error now, it says:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    mb.mandelbrot(-0.5, 0, 1)
  File "C:/Users/GreatOne/Desktop/Master Folder/09/09/ClassyMandelbrot.py", line 19, in mandelbrot
    draw(self.pen, side, u0, v0, x, y);
NameError: global name 'draw' is not defined
>>>

Comment: That, as you've noticed, is independent of this and should be in a separate question. But think about why you think the name should exist.